# Why tooltip is not working when I hover over?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a toggle button using the bootstrap toggle plugin and wanted a tooltip to pop-up when I hover over it.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-size="mini" data-toggle="toggle" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Automatic Refresh is ON" data-onstyle="success" />


<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-hover="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>
```

When I used `data-hover="tooltip"`, it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is a link to the code I've got so far - http://jsbin.com/zexijemija/edit?html,output

Comment: There are no elements in your HTML matching the `[data-toggle="tooltip"]` selector...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Will it work if I change it to `$('[data-hover="tooltip"]').tooltip();` ??

Answer (score 0):

Put `data-toggle="tooltip"`

instead of

`data-toggle="toggle"`

and also learn more about selectors in jQuery. :)

Comment: I am using `data-toggle="toggle"` for the sliding button. So I can't change that.

Comment: @KematRochi change the selector in jQuery which points to that element.

Answer (score 0):

Your input element has `data-toggle="toggle"` while you are calling `.tooltip()` on non-existing elements with selector `[data-toggle="tooltip"]`.

So either change input data attribute value or selector to match.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to select your button :

```
<input id="foo" type="checkbox" data-size="mini" data-toggle="toggle" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Automatic Refresh is ON" data-onstyle="success" />

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#foo").tooltip();   
});
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktptab62/)

Comment: What if you have 1000 tooltip elements? Than add 1000 different IDs and call same function 1000 times?

Comment: I use a class. But if you have only one button ;)